# Width percentage with margin and different nestings

Tags: html, css, width, margin

In my webpage I have a left and a right part, they are not on the same nesting though. I want the left part to fill 25% of the page and the right part to fill the rest of the width.
Simply putting 75% isn't cutting it for me because the right part also needs a 30px right `margin`. A right `padding` won't work because my content and `background-color` overflows then.
Do you have an idea how to solve this?
The .`left` (blue) and `.right`(yellow) `div` should always perfectly meet each other and the `.right` needs to keep it's 30px right `margin`.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  /*padding-right: 30px;*/
  margin-right: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">TEST</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">TEST</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to create a layout using  **only** absolute position. You may better rely on flexbox for example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  flex: 4;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">TEST</div>
<div class="right">TEST</div>
```

But in case you want to keep your code, you need to consider the margin within the calculation of the width:

```css
body {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(75% - 30px);
  right: 0px;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 0;
  /*padding-right: 30px;*/
  margin-right: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">TEST</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">TEST</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that calc(75% - 30px) method - that helped a lot :)